# P=NP in Exponential Space?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, sha, space-complexity, np-complete

Suppose that we find that, for any NP-complete problem, there is an algorithm that can solve it in P time. However, the algorithm takes exponential space. For example, the algorithm to revert SHA256 would only take 256 steps. But you would need 2^256 bits to write the algorithm. Is the time complexity of this algorithm P? Would P equal NP?

The Clay Math Institute says that "Informally the class P is the class of decision problems solvable by some algorithm within a number of steps bounded by some fixed polynomial in the length of the input."
It makes no limitations to the space taken by this algorithm.

We also commonly say that a binary decision tree with depth d can be executed in time-complexity O(d), even if the tree's length might be 2^d.

On the other hand, we know that P is contained within PSPACE.

Comment: If the algorithm takes polynomial time, it doesn't have time to look at more than polynomial amount of the space, and thus should work in polynomial space.

Comment: This sounds like a better question for [cs.se] rather than Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for more specific programming questions. This seems to be more of a general algorithm/theoretical question.

Comment: Decision trees don't have time complexity; algorithms using them, which might only look at a subset, do.

Comment: reading or writing to exponential space will require exponential time

Comment: @IłyaBursov, think of a memory chip with 1024 entries. You don't take 1024 steps to reach the final entry. You only take 10 steps.

Comment: @ScottHunter, thank you, I edited it for greater clarity. I understand time complexity well, but space complexity is more confusing to me, which is why I had to pose the question.

Comment: @GS to read all 1024 entries you need 1024 steps, to read single final entry you need 1 single step

Comment: @IłyaBursov, thank you. This algorithm would work like a binary decision tree, so it would only have to read n entries, not 2^n entries. It would jump up and down an exponentially long memory space, but if that could be done efficiently, then the whole algorithm could take only P time.

Comment: A very similar problem is treated here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39686/does-this-proof-sketch-show-that-finding-a-sha-1-preimage-is-np-hard. Essentially, the point is that once you make the lookup table of 2^256 entries, the problem is bounded. To talk about asymptotic complexity, the problem must be able to scale towards infinity.

Comment: @nielsen That's exactly right, this is just a solution lookup table. Can you explain what you mean by "the problem must be able to scale towards infinity"? Is that related to the SHA/NP-complete problems?

Comment: @nielsen Basically what this got me thinking is, if we know P is in PSPACE, and there does exist a P algorithm in EXPSPACE, then why shouldn't there be a P algorithm in PSPACE as well? Even if the algorithm is very hard to find, the main question in P=NP is not whether the algorithm is easy to find, but whether it exists at all. It would be very consequential if such a compact algorithm existed.

Comment: @nielsen I'm sure it is more complex than this, but that is exactly what I want to understand.

Comment: @GS The problem with your example is that the algorithm must be able to handle input of arbitrary large size "n" and the (asymptotic) complexity is defined as "n" increases towards infinity. An algorithm based on a finite lookup table can only handle problems up to a given size (determined by the size of the lookup table) and thus we cannot let "n" increase towards infinity. Therefore, this is not an example of an algorithm with polynomial complexity.